# Tag (maxima) or (macsyma)?

Tags: discussion, tagging

The tag [maxima](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/maxima) was created in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/174021/complex-equation-in-maxima); according to tag-wiki it is intended for the computer algebra system [Maxima](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxima_%28software%29).

I am afraid that a such tag might easily confuse users posting questions; despite the fact that there is tag excerpt, some users might use this tag for questions about finding maxima and minima of functions. This happened [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/180225/revisions), for example.

Would it be reasonable to rename this tag to [macsyma](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/macsyma) or [maxima-software](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/maxima-software) or something similar. (According to Wikipedia article, Maxima was based on [Macsyma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Macsyma); so these two programs are probably quite similar.)

Or, perhaps, would it be better to use more general tag [computer-algebra-systems](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/computer-algebra-systems) instead?

---

I'll copy here the tag-excerpt and tag-wiki, which were created by [Zev Chonoles](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/174023/revisions), so that they are not lost if the tag is deleted.

Tag-excerpt: For questions concerning the open source computational software program Maxima.

Tag-wiki: For questions concerning the open source computational software program Maxima. [The website for Maxima](http://maxima.sourceforge.net/) has documentation, a wiki, and other useful resources.

Comment: I wonder what Bill has to say about that, being one of the developers of Macsyma and all that...

Comment: I agree about the potential for confusion. Probably maxima-software works best, since there are some major differences between Macsyma and Maxima, so it may be useful to distinguish them. Or we could use Macsyma with an additional tag of free vs. commercial software.

Comment: @BillDubuque Could you perhaps post your suggestion about [tag:maxima-software] as an answer. If it gets a few upvotes and there are no objections, we can do this. (Do this = Either rename the tag, in which case a mod would have to do it, or simply retag the question, copy the tag-wiki to a new tag and let the empty tag die. The second possibility is available for all users, not only mods.)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I agree about the potential for confusion. Probably [maxima-software](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/maxima-software) works best, since there are some major differences between Macsyma and Maxima, so it may be useful to distinguish them. See my comment to the question for another possibility (not mentioned here else it would not be clear which choice the votes are for).

Comment: I think that 8 upvotes (and absence of downvotes/objections) can be considered a consensus can be considered a consensus.

Comment: Willie mentioned [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4697/what-exactly-is-estimation-theory#comment18306_4697) something about possibility of renaming of tags by mods. I don't know whether in that way tag-wiki is transferred to. If it is just about avoiding bumps and tag-wiki must be copied manually, then any user can do it - and in this case bumping a single post is far from being a problem. Please, let me know whether I should keep this for mods or I should do the changes myself.

Comment: Since nothing was done with this question, I [retagged](http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/174021/revisions) the question and copied the [tag-wiki](http://math.stackexchange.com/tags/maxima-software/info) from the one originally created by Zev. I guess that if it was done by mods the only possible difference would be having Zev still as a creator of tag-wiki. (Although I am not sure about that.) I hope this is not too much of a problem - although I don't want to make earning [research assistant badge](http://math.stackexchange.com/badges/176/research-assistant) more difficult for him.